# I cannot show vowel in string with for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

When my string is `jupyter` I want to see `u e j p y t r` but it doesn't work and I cannot see any errors.

```js
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    const vowelArray = [...s];
    let result = [];

    const newArray = vowelArray.reduce((target, item) => {
        switch (item) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                target['first'].push(item);
                break;

            default:
                target['second'].push(item);
                break;
        }

        return target;
    }, {first: [], second: []});

    result = [...newArray['first'], ...newArray['second']].map(item => console.log(item))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify what result do you want to achieve and what result to you get. Also add an example of function execution.

Comment: If you edit your post, there is an icon on the editor looking like `<>` which allows you to make an on site example of the issue.  Please do so.

Comment: what is input and desired output?

Comment: i want to see that when my string is "jupyter"
u
e
j
p
y
t
r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return your result from the function:

```js
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    const vowelArray = [...s];

    const newArray = vowelArray.reduce((target, item) => {
        switch (item) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                target['first'].push(item);
                break;

            default:
                target['second'].push(item);
                break;
        }

        return target;
    }, {first: [], second: []});

    return [...newArray['first'], ...newArray['second']].map(item => console.log(item))
}

vowelsAndConsonants('jupyter');
```

Comment: @Dhaval Pandey i ve just taken an error with your code: 
JavaScript error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on line 4

Comment: @zizzygirl That's another question, which is not related to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method to achieve vowels in an array could be a for loop.

```
function getVowels(arr){
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
if(arr[i] == 'a' ||arr[i] == 'e' ||arr[i] =='i' ||arr[i] =='o' ||arr[i] =='u){
console.log(arr[i];
}
}
}
```

Comment: Although your answer gives a good alternative to what the OP was trying to achieve, this doesn't answer her question of why her code was not working.

Comment: @Dhaval Pandey i fixed this 'u' and console.log(arr[i]); but again its not working